# Combining several layers in ArcGIS Desktop using Intersect gives WARNING 000117: Warning empty output generated?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.3, intersect, warning-000117

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3

I have the following 4 layers (all are polygons)

You can find these layers in [**this link**](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3mzmqrwr8pb9b7i/AADP2mnjxqpG8wRfqcm6RMR3a?dl=0)

**DATA**

1. `Sites`: 5 subcatchments (Site1 to site5) and site 5 combine all
   subcatchments upstream
2. `Nloss`: nitrogen loss for each polygon
3. `Geology`: Rock types
4. `Soils`: Soil types

[image]

**What I want**?

I want to create a polygon shapefile. In this layer, each polygon will have ALL the attributes from all the 4 layers.

I used `intersect` to do so. I think `union` could be used as well to do the same.

I named the resulting shapefile `intersect_4_layers.shp`. The result of this intersection could be found in [**this link**](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bmaflu24ivtwazn/AAD3RDAmkQlVEr6Ol5mDufvXa?dl=0).

**Adding slope**

I have slope shapefile that has two categories (`0` and `1`).

- zero: if slope is less than or equal 10
- 1: if slope is more than 10

  [image]

I wanted to add slope information to the shapefile resulting from intersecting the 4 layers above (Sites/Soils/Nloss/Rocks) named "intersect_4_layers.shp".

I tried the following:

1- to intersect `slope.shp` with `intersect_4_layers.shp`

2- to intersect all 5 layers (`Sites`, `Nloss`, `Geology`, `Soils` and `Slope`)

Both trials failed and resulted in this warning

> WARNING 000117: Warning empty output generated

**QUESTION**

Why intersection worked the 1st time (intersecting 4 layers) and didn't work while trying to intersect them with the slope?

Any suggestions how to get all the attributes of the 5 layers into one shapefile?

Comment: Can you confirm that slope is indeed a vector layer?

Comment: Yes, it is a vector layer. You can find it in this link 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3mzmqrwr8pb9b7i/AADP2mnjxqpG8wRfqcm6RMR3a?dl=0

Comment: I get the same issue with ArcGIS 10.4.1. But it works when you export the output to a gdb feature class. You can convert it to shp afterwards.

Comment: @GISGe
Thanks. Could you please let me know how to export as a gdb feature class?

Comment: Just save the output to a file gdb. If you don't have any, create one with the  'New Geodatabase' button on the top right corner of the Output Feature Class window.

Comment: often with these issues my first troubleshooting step is to repair geometry on all layers. If often works

Comment: @GISGe
Many thanks for your time and help. I followed your suggestions and it worked fine. But I got another problem. I want to calculate the area in ha for each polygon in the result of intersecting the 5 layers. I did this through calculate geometry but I got this message 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sn0stku0i2lgxz2/46.png?dl=0

I exported the attribute table as .dbf and I tried to import it into RStudio but RStudio crashed. I will highly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: @GISGe
Could you please write your comment as an answer?

Comment: Done! Regarding your other question, there must be an error in your Calculate Field expression. I suggest you use [Add Geometry Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-geometry-attributes.htm), this tool will add and calculate the desired geometry fields in 1 step, without expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue with ArcGIS 10.4.1. As a workaround, you can save the output of the Intersect tool as a feature class in a file geodatabase, then the tool will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I have tried following your suggestion regarding Add Geometry Attributes. However, I got error 000732:Dataset 5layers does not exist or is  not supported, when I inserted the layer name in the input feautures in Add Geometry Attributes window. Any suggestions how to fix this? I will highly appreciate if you could try calculating the area in ha to check these errors. Thanks

Comment: Glad it works now. For the area calculation, I don't have your data anymore to test unfortunately. Otherwise you can do it the old way, add a 'double' field and use this expression in the Calculate Field (PYTHON parser): `!shape.area@hectares!` See [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C9E46547D3B246C1B89A36B0C84F7BA8) for reference.

Comment: I will appreciate any help with this question
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223498/exporting-geodatabase-feature-class-to-shapefile-changes-the-attribute-table