# How to export large attribute table from Arcmap and import it into R?

Tags: r, attribute-table, import, arcgis-10.4, dbf

I intersected 5 shapefiles (**[you can find the question and data here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220516/problem-with-combining-several-layers)**) to get polygon shapefile. In which, each polygon has ALL the attributes from the 5 layers.

You can find the shapefile resulting from this intersection in [**this link**](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5B6N7WsEfbdZHlDRVBhTEI0S0k?usp=sharing).

I want to process the attribute table in R. I exported the attribute table as .dbf file. You can find the `.dbf` file in [**this link**](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5B6N7WsEfbdU1ozcFlTOTFLYnM?usp=sharing)

I tried to import it to R as below

```
library(foreign)
df <- read.dbf("5layers1.dbf")
```

I got errors (below) and RStudio crashed so I couldn't get `sessionInfo()`. 
[image]

---

As [@Vince pointed out below](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220957/how-to-export-large-attribute-table-from-arcmap-and-import-it-into-r?noredirect=1#comment340065_220957), it is unlikely I will be able to import it to R because of the large size.

Do you have any suggestions how to export large attribute table and import it into R?

Comment: Please always add error messages as text within the question body. This makes them legible on all devices, and allows anyone with the same error to locate your question.  It's unlikely you will be able to import a dBase file in excess of 2^31-1 bytes, since the format specification does not permit it.

Comment: The error message is clear: this is an invalid DBF file because it's too large, as @Vince points out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about GIS.

Comment: @whuber
I think it is not off-topic. I think gis.stackexchange is where many users have large size shapefile and attribute table and I want to consult their experience how to handle large attribute table and what is the best way to export them from arcmap and import them in ArcGIS.

Comment: That is not what you are asking: you are just reporting an error reading a file.

Comment: @whuber
Thanks. I updated the question. Please, check the updates

Comment: @whuber
I changed the question title as well.

Comment: Have you tried loading your shapefiles into a file geodatabase and accessing the intersect result from there using R?  I'm assuming that R can read simple feature classes in file geodatabases via the File Geodatabase API.

Comment: @PolyGeo
Thanks for your suggestion. I managed to fix the problem through exporting the attribute table as .txt file and I managed to import it easily in R as it can handle large .txt files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try loading your shapefiles into a file geodatabase, intersecting them there, and accessing the resultant intersect feature class from there using R.

I'm assuming that R can read simple feature classes in file geodatabases via the File Geodatabase API.