# Exporting geodatabase feature class to shapefile changes the attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, attribute-table, arcgis-10.4

I'm using ArcGIS 10.4.1

**DATA**

I have several layers. I combined all of them into one layer using `union`. I saved the result of union in geodatabase based on the suggestion by [@GISGe](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220516/problem-with-combining-several-layers/220704#220704).

You can download the data from [**this link**](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5B6N7WsEfbdRG9GYm93OENSMjA?usp=sharing).

**METHOD**

I wanted to convert the geodatabase feature class to shapefile.

I did this using `Feature Class to Feature Class`. It went well without any errors however I found the columns of the attribute table of the shapefile created after using `Feature Class to Feature Class` messy as shown below.

**BEFORE** using `Feature Class to Feature Class`

[image]

**AFTER** using `Feature Class to Feature Class`
[image]

Any suggestions how can I fix this problem?

**UPDATE**

In response to the comments

- I have tried using right-click on the feature class in the geodatabase and export it to shapefile but it didn't work.
- I have tried Copy Features but it gave me the same result.
- I'm exporting the feature class to a different location not to the same geodatabase

Comment: That shapefile is corrupted. This is not the usual outcome of this command.

Comment: You can use ArcCatalog,  and go to the geodatabase file, right-click on the file and select export to shapefile.

Comment: I'm not in the habit of downloading corrupt data from unknown sources.

Comment: From an Internet safety standpoint, **all** data from unknown sources is corrupt. This is *particularly* true of google drives. If you're waiting for me to download, it ain't gonna happen.

Comment: Perhaps Copy Features instead?

Comment: It may be 'slightly broken' in the database.. try compressing (a copy of) the database, if that doesn't work export to XML recordset http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/exporting-a-geodatabase-schema-to-an-xml-workspace-document.htm then import into a fresh database - this is a drastic fix for broken databases and often works. Altertately if you can view your database feature class in ArcMap right click on it and export to shapefile - it works differently to a geoprocessing tool and might not be as susceptible to corruption.

Comment: @Vince the gdb fc has 1.3 million features. Could the OP be running into a memory/space limitation in the shapefile format?

Comment: @aelwan You might try splitting the feature class into 2, then converting to see if you're hitting a size limitation. And/or converting it to another geodatabase feature class first--see if that works correctly.

Comment: Try QGIS to convert the geodatabase feature class to shape

Comment: You don't need to convert your feature class to shapefile to calculate the area of polygons (if this calculation is what you want to do ultimately)

Comment: You may have already done these but I'd aprobably try a repair geometry, and then remove and recreate any spatial and attribute indexes before converting to a shapefile.  I'd also try QGIS too.

Comment: Are you exporting to the same database as the initial feature class?

Comment: @GISGe
Thanks for your time and help. You are right. I can use calculate areas to calculate the area of feature class within geodatabase. However, I want to do other calculations.

Comment: @aelwan This is not a chat forum - Please [edit] your Question in response to comments, rather than replying in comments.  Put any extra information into your question.

Comment: @aelwan Thanks for accepting my answer. I can't think of calculations you can do on a shapefile but not on a geodatabase feature class (with ArcGIS/arcpy at least), so if you have trouble doing these, please post a new question, I'd be glad to help

Comment: @GISGe
Many thanks for your time and help. I'll try and post a question if I find a trouble. I can't award you the bounty now. It will be possible after 3 hrs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a bug discovered in ArcGIS 10.3, so it probably applies to newer versions since it hasn't been solved:

[Bug BUG-000084520 - Field values in a shapefile attribute table are corrupted when viewed in ArcGIS 10.3.](http://support.esri.com/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA4NDUyMA==)

It shouldn't occur in older versions, but I can't test this to confirm, and it's probably not a convenient option for you neither.

Working with geodatabase feature classes instead of shapefiles seems to me to be the most reasonable (and easy) alternative.